LQR gains sign is negative (possible or not)?
Is it possible that the gains for an attitude control problem computed on MatLab with the respective function, turn out negative? It's LTV linearized system.

Welcome to Robotics, user41850. My first reaction is, "Did you setup the equation correctly?" and my second reaction is, "Does it work?" Typically I would expect $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$, and then there's an assumption that $u = -Kx$, and you solve for $K$, the gains, but if you assumed that $u = Kx$ then the negative would essentially distribute into the gains themselves; it's all a matter of formulation. Can you please edit your question to include your system, how you calculated the gains, and some plots of the system response with and without the controller?

Thank you for the quick answer. Actually I have used lqr MatLab function, which, from what i got, computes u = -Kx, so it's not that I have specified this in my code. Then, what i get is 3x6xt array, and the matrices have negative and positive values as well, but the ones on the diagonals are more or less all negative. By computing the eigenvalues over time, they turn out to be all negative real part, but when I try the gains at the simulator, it seems to oscillate really too much
